# Как получить переменные в php с ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Как получить доступ к переменной `$datastring`.
ХТМЛ КОД:

```
<form action="./js/reservations.php" method="post" class="reservationForm" id="reservationForm">

                <!-- column 1 -->
                <div class="col col_1_2 alpha">
                    <div class="row field_select">
                        <label>Choose medical department:</label><br />

                    </div>

                    <div class="row field_text">
                         <label>Your full name:</label><br />
                        <input name="name" value="" id="name" class="inputtext required" size="40" type="text" />
                    </div>

                    <div id = 'emailId' class="row field_text">
                        <label>Your email address:</label><br />
                      <input name="email" value="" id="email" class="inputtext required" size="40" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="submit" value="MAKE APPOINTMENT" id="send" class="btn-send" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/ column 1 -->

                <!-- column 2 -->
                <div class="col col_1_2 omega">
                    <div class="row field_date">

                        <div id="date_in"></div>
                        <input name="date_in_input" value="" id="date_in_input" type="hidden" />

                        <div class="notice_table"><span class="square-green">your selection</span> <span class="square-disable">not available</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/ column 2 -->

                <div class="field_submit">
                    <p class="sending"><img id="sending" src="./images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" /></p>

                </div>
            </form>
```

Это присоединенный js код

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
tfuse_reservations_form();

                    });

function tfuse_reservations_form(){
var my_error;
jQuery("#send").bind("click", function(){

my_error = false;
jQuery("#reservationForm input, #reservationForm textarea, #reservationForm radio, #reservationForm select").each(function(i)
{
            var surrounding_element = jQuery(this);
            var value               = jQuery(this).attr("value");
            var check_for           = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            var required            = jQuery(this).hasClass("required");

            if(check_for == "email"){
                surrounding_element.removeClass("error valid");
                baseclases = surrounding_element.attr("class");
                if(!value.match(/^\w[\w|\.|\-]+@\w[\w|\.|\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)){
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("error");
                    my_error = true;
                }else{
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("valid");
                }
            }

            if(required && check_for != "email"){
                surrounding_element.removeClass("error valid");
                baseclases = surrounding_element.attr("class");
                if(value == ""){
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("error");
                    my_error = true;
                }else{
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("valid");
                }
            }

           if(jQuery("#reservationForm input, #reservationForm textarea, #reservationForm radio, #reservationForm select").length  == i+1){
                if(my_error == false){
                    jQuery("#reservationForm p.notice, #reservationForm #send").hide();
                    jQuery("#reservationForm p.sending").show();

                    var $datastring = "ajax=true";
                    jQuery("#reservationForm input, #reservationForm textarea, #reservationForm radio, #reservationForm select").each(function(i)
                    {
                        var $name = jQuery(this).attr('name');
                        $value = encodeURIComponent(jQuery(this).attr('value'));
                        $datastring = $datastring + "&" + $name + "=" + $value;
                    });

                jQuery.ajax({
                       type: "POST",

                       data: $datastring,
                          url: "./js/reservations.php",
                       success: function(response){
                           jQuery("#reservationForm p.sending, #reservationForm p.notice").hide();
                           if(response) {
                              alert('сообещние отправлено')
                           } else {
                              alert('нет')
                           }
                       }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
        return false;
});
```

}

В файле php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$date = $_POST['data'];
```

Comment: Что у вас в переменной datastring? И зачем мешать js и php?

Comment: Это называется примерно так.

>показать чистый исходник в новом окнеСкрыть/показать номера >строкпечать кода с сохранением подсветки

Скопировали из одного непонятного места и вставили на форум, пусть ребята разберутся как оно работает, ну а я опять копипаст себе. Опять не заработает, задам еще один вопрос, опять ответят, опять проверю.

Ну видно же что из примера брали код, так почему же весь пример сюда не вставить-то?

Comment: тревога -> работа за автора, или я не прав? =\

Comment: Сами же попросили вставить весь код!

Answer (score 1):

$datastring в данном случае будет вида:

```
$datastring={id: 1, name: "My name", mail: "my@mail.ru", };
```

в php-скрипт передаются переменные id, mail, name. Выдергивать их нужно из массива $_GET или $_POST - зависит от метода передачи

Comment: В php файле прописываю вот так:

     <?php
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $date = $_POST['date'];


     ?>

Но данный php файл не начинает обрабатываться

Comment: Если я удаляю код, расположенный в первом посте, тогда работает. В чем причина?

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `$datastring`-a подставляете то, что вам нужно. Это не переменная, а селектором делается. Например, если у вас есть некое поле с `id=test (`<input id="test" value="mydata" />`)`, то значение `mydata` берется вот так:

```
$('#test').val();
```

А ответный код с "succes"-а ловите.

Comment: У меня календарик, который находится не в хтмл документе. У него ведь нет idб Человек выберет значение(дату), мне необходимо получить эту дату, а на сайте эту дату сделать недоступной. 
В $datastring все удачно помещается, только я не могу отправить на сервер все это дело.